# Appending multiple times when using .trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the button append "Texted Marked" three times when I click on it the first time?
And then, it appends the same string two times, the second time I click on the button.

I would appreciate your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").select(function(){
    $("ul").append(" Text marked!");
  });
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("input").trigger("select");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>
    
<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, I'm unable to reproduce this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pudukufito/edit?html,js,console,output) perhaps you prevent can event bubbling on button click? like: ```$("button").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $("input").trigger("select"); });```

Comment: @Varinder You got it, when you click on the button, it appends three times the string 'Text Marked!'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [doc](https://api.jquery.com/select/):

> To trigger the event manually, apply .select() without an argument

```
$( "#other").click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).select();
});
```

So try this:

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>

<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
<ul></ul>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("input").select();
            $("ul").append(" Text marked!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE.**
if you try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").select(function(){
        alert("Text marked!");
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").select();
    });
});
```

alert will appear 2 times, so I think the reason is that you have 2 words and event triggers for each word.

Comment: Irrespective of input number of words, it's giving three times alert. Tried in debugging tool.

Comment: @Chip yes, you are right! for the first time it's giving 3 alerts, but if click button once more it's giving 2 alerts.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`.triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) instead of `.trigger`, the text won't be selected though:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").select(function(){
    $("ul").append(" Text marked!");
  });
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("input").triggerHandler("select");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>
    
<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
<ul></ul>
```

The difference between `.trigger` and `.triggerHandler` is as the name implies: `.trigger` will trigger the event, while `.triggerHandler` will merely invoke the handler for the event (so you could say that `.trigger` tries to replicate an actual event, but `.triggerHandler` doesn't try to do that at all).

Alternatively, there is this little hack as well (which you may find more favorable, since the text inside the input will be selected):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var attachSelectEventToInput = function() {
    $("input").one("select", function(){
      $("ul").append(" Text marked!");
    });
  };

  $("button").click(function(){
    attachSelectEventToInput();
    $("input").trigger("select");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>
    
<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
<ul></ul>
```

---

To be honest, I am surprised as well that the `"select"` handler is called 3 times, regardless of the number of words your input element has.

**Update**: just tested this in Firefox and IE11, nothing odd. Opera and Chrome show this behavior though, so I am thinking it may be V8-exclusive.

Comment: I know. It's surprising. I really want to know why this is happening.